# Conditional varience of random var

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation

Say i have two discrete rv's $X,Y$ and let y be a value Y can take on with non zero probability.

Is $Var(X|Y=y)$ given by:

$E((X|Y=y)^2)+E(X|Y=y)^2$ or by $E(X^2|Y=y)+E(X|Y=y)^2$

I believe that the two expressions are actually the same thing, is this correct?

Comment: What does it mean to square the expression $X \mid Y = y$?

Comment: @heropup Well in my understanding, we are squaring the result of the random variable $(X|Y=y)$ which is equivelent to $(X^2|Y=y)$ Correct?

Comment: Somebody should look for definitions in some textbook here... Note that (X|Y=y) is not a random variable, actually (X|Y=y) does not exist.